# Is there a way to clear the cache history of input autocomplete

Tags: javascript, forms, input, autocomplete, browser-cache

I am wondering if we could clear up the history of autocomplete, please do not say set autocomplete = off as it is not my intend.

right now I have below code which shows the user entry history.

```
  <form>
    <input type="text" id="leftMenuSearch" autocomplete="on"
      placeholder="<cfoutput>#getLang('myhome',655)#</cfoutput>" />
    &nbsp;<div class="search"><i class="catalyst-magnifier"></i></div>
  </form>
```

[image]

Comment: Can [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15738259/disabling-chrome-autofill) help you?

Comment: @Ashkan the thread is about disabling, though I am asking how to clear up the input fill, not disabling it. The user will keep using it however if it fills with unwanted information, he will clear up and will keep using it.